# How do I *not* supply a column for update in EF?

Tags: entity-framework

I am sure I am not the first one to struggle with this.

I am using Entity Framework 1 (VS2008) and one of the columns in the table is ModifiedDate. It has DefaultValue in SQL Server (getdate()); so I would like to leave it the DB to do the generation. However, generated SQL has `INSERT (... ModifiedDate) VALUES (... null)`, and the default value doesn't get inserted.

Is it possible to **not** specify this column at all?

Comment: Felix you're right, it's been a while since I fired up an entity framework project...those attributes aren't shared between the two at all, my mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting [StoreGeneratedPattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.storegeneratedpattern.aspx) in SSDL.

Comment: Craig, thank you! In conversation with Nick above I came to the same conclusion; but when Nick deleted the thread (because it veered into LINQ to SQL territory) - my belated finding was deleted as well. It's nice to have your answer - so others can benefit!